# App Review Information section is not getting saved in the App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have been trying to save my app information in `App Store Connect` since yesterday as I wanted to push my app to the `App Store` however the saving process gets stuck, which means it does not stops loading. I have noticed that the saving process keeps on loading only whenever I add/edit the details in the `App Review Information` section, elsewhere it is working.

[image]

I have tried the same process several times in the following ways:

- Checked internet connection stability
- Connecting to different networks
- Switching to a new browser
- Reloading the page
- Reopening it on a new tab
- Toggling the Sign In Required checkbox

Is anybody else facing similar issues and what measures should I follow for the resolution of these issues?

Comment: Hey there I am facing now the same problem. Do you have a solution for that? Thank you in advance

Comment: I got it! I tried it with my windows-pc and then it worked!

Comment: @rottler35 I have not got any firm solution for the issue and trying out on the windows platform didn't work for my case.

Comment: I did exactly the same and it worked, but thanks for the answer

Comment: Great! I will try performing the same on other window devices. Thanks for the tip though! ;)